# Open several text files at once with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I edit several CSS files at once (because of the [SMACSS](https://smacss.com/) CSS architecture) and it's quite annoying to open all 4 each time anew, several times a day, because you need to navigate to the directory of each file by itself:

```
your_theme_name/css/base/base.css
your_theme_name/css/component/component.css
your_theme_name/css/layout/layout.css
your_theme_name/css/theme/theme.css
```

Is there a way to make some kind of a shortcut to enter the paths of all 4 files to open them at once in the sorting I'll want?

Comment: The most obvious solution for me in this case is: Never close Notepad++. Even if you go home, just put your computer into Sleep mode. Problem solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I edit several CSS files at once, how can I open them all at the same time?

You can make use of the Notepad++ Session Manager.

**To save a session:**

- Start Notepad++
- Open the files you want to have in the session.
- "File" > "Save Session..."
- Give your session a session "Name" and a "Link" (name of the session file), then click "OK"

  [image]
- Close Notepad++

**To restore a session:**

- Start Notepad++
- "File" > "Load Session..."
- Browse to the the saved session and click "OK"

  [image]

---

#### Sessions And Projects

> **How to store and retrieve sets of files as they were opened in
>   Notepad++**
>
> Sessions keep track of what files are opened in Notepad++, with some
>   extra information like file positions and highlighter for the file.
>   The detailed contents of session files is described in the relevant
>   section of Editing Configuration Files. Sessions do not backup files -
>   see Settings -> Preferences -> Backup/Auto-Completion about this.
>
> There are exactly 5 controls in Notepad++ that relate to sessions:
>
> - File -> Load session....
> - File -> Save session....
> - Settings -> Preferences -> Backup -> Remember current session for next launch
> - Settings -> Preferences -> Backup -> Enable session snapshots and periodic backups*
> - Settings -> Preferences -> MISC -> Session file ext.:
>
> ...
>
> **Session files**
>
> They are plain xml files, with some obvious structure you can borrow
>   from existing session. This means you can edit them manually, if this
>   is easier. In particular, session files will record bookmarks and how
>   text is folded.
>
> By default, session files have the .xml extension, but you can change
>   that from Settings -> Preferences -> MISC -> Session file ext (look in
>   the lower right corner).
>
> session.xml does not get renamed when you change the default session
>   extension. This is not an issue, because you can ask Notepad++ to load
>   any file, as long as it has contents that can be understood.

Source [Sessions And Projects](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Sessions_And_Projects)

Answer (score 4):

### Using shell scripts

When you run the command `notepad++ <file1> <file2> ...` it opens all of those files in notepad++.

Using this feature, you can make a script for each set of files that will open all the files listed.

I'm assuming you're on windows because you're using notepad++ so here's how to do that for windows.

### How to make a script

- Open up your favorite text editor (probably notepad++)
- Type in the command you want to run (probably `notepad++ <file1> <file2> ...`
- Save the file as `<name>.bat`